# Class cast exception with oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting Exception in first line of the below code

> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection$$EnhancerByProxool$$3415e85 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection

How can i convert string to `oracle.sql.Clob` and how to insert using `PreparedStatement`.

```
// con is java.sql.Connection object
oracle.sql.CLOB newClob = oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(con, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

newClob.putString(1,transcript); 
pstmt.setClob(1, newClob);
pstmt.setString(2, StringUtils.dateToMillis(endTime));
pstmt.setString(3, sessionID);
int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("updated count ::"+count);
System.out.println("transcript updated....");
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in the code that comes before the snippet you've included. Where are you getting the connection from? Also, look at the stacktrace to find the exact line that is causing the issue.

Comment: exactly im getting the exception in first line only...

Comment: transcript is a string (consists of xml data) and endtime is java.util.Date object and sessionID is string) ... problem with first line only, when im trying to create clob object

Answer (score 2):

```
Clob clob = connection.createClob();
clob.setString(1, transcript);
```

Or simly use the setClob() method takin a reader as argument:

```
pstmt.setClob(1, new StringReader(transcript));
```

No need to use any database-proprietary class. JDBC is supposed to be an database-agnostic abstraction layer.

Comment: it returning java.sql.Clob object... will it store into Database as CLOB object

Comment: Clob is an interface. The Oracle JDBC connection will return an Oracle implementation of this interface. Also see my edited answer.